# Copying/reassigning `std::stringbuf` in C++

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, copying

I'm writing a class that writes data to the terminal from a socket. In order to test some of my methods, I've got a setter method for one of my class variables, which happens to be a `std::stringbuf` object. When trying to assign a new object to the class instance, my editor is showing an error in the assignment. For clarity, here is my class prototype:

```
class MainServer : BaseServer 
{
    public:
        MainServer();
        void setByteBuffer(std::stringbuf);
    private:
        int valread;
        std::stringbuf byteBuffer;
        void dataRead();
        void terminalWrite();
};
```

The method that is giving mew trouble is `setByteBuffer`, the implementation is:

```
void MainServer::setByteBuffer(std::stringbuf testByteBuffer)
{
    byteBuffer = testByteBuffer;
}
```

The error my editor is giving me is:

```
std::stringbuf &std::stringbuf::operator=(const std::stringbuf &)
+1 overload

@brief %Vector assignment operator.
@param __x A %vector of identical element and allocator types.

All the elements of @a __x are copied, but any unused capacity in
@a __x will not be copied.

Whether the allocator is copied depends on the allocator traits.

function "std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> &) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" (declared at line 140 of "/usr/include/c++/9/sstream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

It seems that the assignment (meant to say copy) constructor for the `stringbuf` class is not suited for what I'm trying to do. What are some ways to fix that? I supposed one solution is to use a `stringbuf *`, but it seems like a bad idea since this will only be used for testing purposes anyway.

Comment: `std::stringbuf` objects are not copyable. There is also no such thing as "assignment constructor". O guess solution would be to use something else instead of `stringbuf`.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write copy constructor. So what else could work for this purpose?

Comment: Well, from the question it is unclear what is the purpose you are using `stringbuf` for.

Comment: I'm using `stringbuf` to store data from a socket. Maybe an alternative would be to use a `vector<char>` object. The key is it needs to be able to hold an indefinite amount of data, so an array is not a good choice.

Comment: Then you definitely should've used `vector` from the beginning.

Comment: The reason I tried to avoid it was because I though storing (potentially) large amounts of data in a `vector` would be worse than `stringbuf`, which I assumed was made for large streams of data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to your error is: [[godbolt example]](https://godbolt.org/z/RynR-s)

```
byteBuffer = std::move(testByteBuffer);
```

`stringbuf` objects are not copyable, but they are movable.

(However as user7860670 pointed out, you might have an easier time using something like `std::vector` or `std::string` as storage instead of `std::stringbuf`. It's hard to suggest an ideal solution without more context to help understand what you are trying to do — if you can get the code working, you might [consider posting on CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for further improvements. Regardless, if your intent is to take ownership of the passed-in object, moving it is a good practice anyway, to avoid unnecessary copying.)